# .Except / Yield return out of memory exception

Tags: c#, linq, out-of-memory, yield-return

I'm running out of memory using Linq's Except statement.

Example:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000);
int i=0;
while (numbers.Any())
{
    numbers = numbers.Except(new List<int> {i++});
}
```

I decompiled the method, this does the same and also gives an out of memory exception.

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000);
int i=0;
while (numbers.Any())
{
   numbers = CustomExcept(numbers, new List<int>{i++});
}
private IEnumerable<int> CustomExcept(IEnumerable<int> numbers, IEnumerable<int> exceptionList)
{
    HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
    foreach (var i in exceptionList)
    {
        set.Add(i);
    }
    foreach (var i in numbers)
    {
        if (set.Add(i))
        {
           yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: why does this throw an out of memory exception?

I would expect the Garbage Collector to clean up the unused HashSets.

Comment: You should be aware of the effects of the deferred execution (achieved with `yield`). Every step executes all the previous steps, starting with `Range` and all `Except`s. And doing it twice (because of the `Any` call).

Comment: Updated the example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are at `i==10` in `numbers.Any()`, that "numbers" is not a list of numbers from 10 until 10 million, rather it is:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000)
   .Except({0})
   .Except({1})
   .Except({2})
   // (etc)
   .Except({9})
```

And all those "Excepts" have their own hashset that is very much live. So there is nothing to garbage collect.

You will have to add some `.ToList()`s to really execute those Excepts and give the garbage collector some chance.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, this is some pretty surprising behavior. I wouldn't have expected `Except` to run out of memory in this case either.

But if you look at the [reference source for the Enumerable class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), you'll see the reason. Except (via an ExceptIterator helper method):

- Creates a new `Set<T>`
- Iterates the second list and adds its elements to the set
- Iterates the first list, and for each element:

  - Tries to add it to the set
  - If it wasn't already present, yield returns it

So it's not *just* doing an "except", it's also implicitly doing a "distinct". And in order to do that "distinct", it's adding all the elements of the *first* list to the set too... so with a huge first list, yes, you'll consume huge amounts of memory.

I would've expected it to do a "contains" in the second loop, not an "add". I don't see this behavior called out in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) either. The closest I see is the description:

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

If it's thinking of its parameters as sets, then it does make sense that it removes duplicates, since that's what sets do. But it's not something I would have predicted from the method name!

Anyway, your best bet is probably to get rid of your `Except`, and instead capture `Last` into a variable and then do a `Where(value => value != last)`.

Comment: I also expected a contains and not an add. But why does the GC not clean up these unused sets after each while loop iteration?

Comment: @Carra During each iteration of the loop there are no sets.  They haven't even been created yet.  The body of the while loop is just constructing a query that defines how an `Except` *will* be performed, it's not performing it.

Comment: A `.Contains()` on any enumerable except another HashSet or Dictionary would require a full scan for every single item in the "outer" enumerable. `Except's behaviour is better in terms of performance and memory usage in almost all cases - scan the Enumerable only once, create a hashset out of it and reuse it.

Comment: To improve this code one would have to detect that the "outer" enumerable is the product of another `Except` operation. The Core team already did this with [Concat.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Concat.cs) in .NET Core 2.0